# Using distinct on in subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

I noticed that in PostgreSQL the following two queries output different results:

```
select a.*
from (
    select distinct on (t1.col1)
        t1.*
    from t1
    order by t1.col1, t1.col2
) a
where a.col3 = value
;
```

```
create table temp as
select distinct on (t1.col1)
    t1.*
from t1
order by t1.col1, t1.col2
;
select temp.*
from temp
where temp.col3 = value
;
```

I guess it has something to do with using `distinct on` in subqueries.

What is the correct way to use `distinct on` in subqueries? E.g. can I use it if I don't use `where` statement?
Or in queries like

```
(
select distinct on (a.col1)
    a.*
from a
)
union
(
select distinct on (b.col1)
    b.*
from b
)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example: sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: IMHO both should return the same result.

Answer (score 1):

In normal situation, both examples should return the same result.

I suspect that you are getting different results because the `order by` clause of your `distinct on` subquery is not deterministic. That is, there may be several rows in `t1` sharing the same `col1` and `col2`.

If the columns in the `order by` do not uniquely identify each row, then the database has to make its own decision about which row will be retained in the resultset: as a consequence, the results are not stable, meaning that consecutive executions of the same query may yield different results.

Make sure that your `order by` clause is deterministic (for example by adding more columns in the clause), and this problem should not arise anymore.

Comment: Then running query 1 several times should also result in different results: `(
    select distinct on (t1.col1)
        t1.*
    from t1
    order by t1.col1, t1.col2
) 
except
(
    select distinct on (t1.col1)
        t1.*
    from t1
    order by t1.col1, t1.col2
) `